# Maven is Trying to use /var/empty/.m2/repository as my Local Repository

Tags: maven, maven-3

This just started a few moments ago. Up until this afternoon, I've been able to run `mvn clean install` from within my project directory with no issues. I tried to do so this afternoon, and got the following error:

```
MusikPolice$ mvn -X clean install
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 11:22:22-0400)
Maven home: /Applications/apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.7.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /Applications/apache-maven-3.1.1/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /var/empty/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /var/empty/.m2/repository
[ERROR] Could not create local repository at /var/empty/.m2/repository -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.repository.LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException: Could not create local repository at /var/empty/.m2/repository
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.validateLocalRepository(DefaultMaven.java:505)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException
```

The wiki page that it suggests I read is not terribly helpful, and just suggests that this may happen if Maven can't write to the `~/.m2/repository/` directory.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you check your env vars?  What is home set to? What maven env vars have you got set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of this log message:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /Applications/apache-maven-3.1.1/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /var/empty/.m2/settings.xml
```

it seems that Maven after had red `/Applications/apache-maven-3.1.1/conf/settings.xml` started reading `/var/empty/.m2/settings.xml`, so check in the `/Applications/apache-maven-3.1.1/conf/settings.xml` if the following lines have been uncommented:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <!-- localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository
  <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
  -->
```

and there is set `localRepository` as `/var/empty/`.